# Do we have standard pipeline option in Azure DevOps to share the library in other pipelines like in jenkins?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, jenkins-pipeline, shared-libraries

I would like to have one standard pipeline defined and want to use that as a shared library in all my jobs which have the common steps.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's called [Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops):

> Use templates to define your logic once and then reuse it several times. Templates combine the content of multiple YAML files into a single pipeline. You can pass parameters into a template from your parent pipeline.

For example, Job reuse:

First yaml:

```
# File: templates/jobs.yml
jobs:
- job: Build
  steps:
  - script: npm install

- job: Test
  steps:
  - script: npm test
```

Second yaml:

```
# File: azure-pipelines.yml

jobs:
- template: templates/jobs.yml  # Template reference
```